# how to adjust the inner elements based on parent height/width changes?

Tags: html, css, styles

I have `ul` , `li` within the `div` which is aligned horizontally.I have used flex dispaly. Here div is the parent container all styles like background, height, width will be applied here.
`li` elements have some inner contents like div,span which can may have text/icon. 
Whenever i adjust the parent div width/height the inner contents all should be adjusted. icon/text (span which is child of li) need to centered. padding will need to adjust. I have edited my needs in below plunker

[plunker link](https://plnkr.co/edit/th0ylX4dccZmoSeURk77?p=preview)

Can you please check with this and let me know any option.Thanks for any suggestion.

Here my css code

```
 .table_ul {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style: none;
  padding:0px;
}
.cells_li {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-right:none;
  padding: .5em;
  text-align: center;
}

.cells_li:last-child {
  border-right: 1px solid red;
}
.main_div {
  background:gray;
  width:400px;
  height:20px;
}
```

below is my html page

```
<div id="group" class="main_div">
        <ul class="table_ul">
            <li class="cells_li"><div><span>desktop</span></div></li>
            <li class="cells_li"><div><span>laptop</span></div></li>
            <li class="cells_li"><div><span>work</span></div></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: You've restricted the height of `.main_div` You'll need to remove that to start with.

Comment: Perhaps you could provide images so we can see how this is **supposed** to look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can assign `float:left` to the LIs and `height:100%` to make them get the parent heights.

```
/* Styles go here */
.table_ul {
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
  list-style: none;
  padding:0px;

}
.cells_li {
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-right:none;
  padding: 0.5em;
  text-align: center;
  width:calc(33% - 1em);
  float:left;display: inline;
  height:calc(100% - 1em);
}

.cells_li:last-child {
  border-right: 1px solid red;
}
.main_div {
  background:gray;
  width:400px;
  height:150px;
}
```

Comment: your code seems good. but my need is i have to apply padding to li. In that case too padding of the child needs to be update based on parent height and width. it should be responsive

Comment: Is this solving your issue?

Comment: yeah  i am checking. facing issue in some other case

Comment: Sh, i have some other alignment issue and its now working fine. With your suggestion i have done my alignments. Thanks